# Godot Procedural 3D collision between static and kinematic bodies

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm developing this collision detector simulator with a static and a kinematic 3D body in it.

The idea for now is to make the kinematic body move via keyboard and to trigger an alarm everytime it collides with the static object.

So far so good. The difficulty stems from the fact that I want this two bodies to be **loadable** from file system (OBJ files).

The static body works like a charm. I load the OBJ as a mesh, delete previous collider and generate the new one with `create_trimesh_collision()`. Just perfect.

The problem comes with the kinematic body.

First af all, I know that trimesh is not supported for kinematic bodies (please correct me if I'm wrong or you know a workaround), so I use the in editor "mesh" button and select "Create single/multiple convex collision siblings" and it just works fine (the multiple option creates quite precise colliders actually).

But if I do that from GDScript using `create_convex_collision()`:

- First, I was quite dissapointed to see that the convex collider created is a simple one (a pity after seeing the good results the "multiple" option gets and reading some posts about this feateure incorporation).
- But what surprised me the most is that after generating this new collider it doesn't collide with the static collider anymore. It just passes through it.

Any ideas on this? Workarounds? Tips? Maybe the kinematic body should be static too? And move it procedurally somehow? Maybe my approach is not the correct one?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you add your GDScript?